# Is it possible to use custom Spring validator to validate method input just like input of controller method in MVC?

Tags: spring, validation

I have custom Spring validator (not constraint-validator!)

```
@Component
public class MyValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator{
   //my fine implementation
}
```

I can use that validator in controller like

```
@RestController
public class MyController{
   @Autowired private MyValidator myValidator;

   @InitBnder
   public void binder(WebDataBinder binder){
     binder.addValidator(myValidator);
   }

   @PostMapping
   public void whatever(@RequestBody @Valid MyValidatedObject){ // not sure is @Valid needed here
      .....
   }
}
```

This works fine on controller level due to manual registration of validator to web binder. Now, I want to use the same validator on service method input, not on contorller level. If I do

```
@Service
@Validated
class MyService{

   public void someMethod(@Valid MyValidatedObject input);

}
```

Validator is not fired. Other annotatons like `@Min` or `@Max` works here (throwing an exception as MyValidatedObject is not valid subject for those - but it shows that validation is about to be triggered). So it seams that only `ConstrainValidator` alike validators works here out of the box. How can I make Spring to use my custom validator to validate method input??

PS obviously I can inject validator and invoke it directly, but that is not what I want.